# A process with ActiveMQ transaction enabled

Tags: distributed-transactions

If a process is using JMS connector as ActiveMQ what will happen to the following transcations, will it commit or rollback,

1. A process having one or two database update calls, if process fails what will happen to database updates ?
2. A process having database and http update: if process fails what will happen to database and http update?
3. A process having one or more HTTP updates and post calls, what will happen to http update and post if process fails ?

I tried doing the poc for the above but bit confused with transactionality with ActiveMQ and its behavior. It seems like transaction is not working any of the above three scenarios.